# OSSEC HIDS cannot ignore rules based on hostname

Tags: ossec

I am attempting to ignore an ossec rule for an alert that is triggered from a certain host.  Rule 5401 exists in the syslog_rules.xml file:

```
<rule id="5401" level="10">
  <if_sid>5400</if_sid>
  <match>3 incorrect password attempts</match>
  <description>Three failed attempts to run sudo</description>
</rule>
```

If this rule is triggered, a level 10 alert level is generated, along with an email

I want to add an exception to this rule in the local_rules.xml file, where if the hostname that sends the alert is ip-10-XX-XX-XX, no email alert will be generated.  I have been able to create this rule in local_rules.xml:

```
<rule id="10040" level="0">
  <if_sid>5401</if_sid>
  <match>myUserName</match>
  <description>List of rules to be ignored.</description>
</rule>
```

And when rule 5401 is triggered by myUserName, no alert is generated.  According to ossec documentation, I should be able to replace the match argument with:

```
<hostname>ip-10-XX-XX-XX</hostname>
```

However this has been unsuccessful, and an email alert still generates when I trigger rule 5401